# React state don't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm updating the state of an object, say like
`obj = { a:1, b: ['hello','bye'] }`  to
`setObj({ a:1, b:['hi','good'] })`. The react re-renders this ParentComponent.

//ParentComponent

```
return (
  <>
    {
      obj.b.map((data,i)=>{
        <ChildComponent greetings={data}/>
      })
    }
  </>
)
```

But it doesn't re-render the ChildComponent, I'm new to react and still exploring new things. Please help me out with this one.

Comment: Please show more code about declare `obj` and the way you call `setObj`

Comment: You should probably also show the child component.

Comment: Your `map` function doesn't return anything. Either remove the `{}` around `<ChildComponent>` (implicit return) or use `return` (explicit return).

Answer (score 0):

If you write like this, the `ChildComponent` won't be render. Instead, you should add a `return`

```
    {
      obj.b.map((data,i)=>{
        return <ChildComponent greetings={data}/>
      })
    }
```

or

```
{
   obj.b.map((data,i)=>(<ChildComponent greetings={data}/>))
}
```

Comment: @IshanVarshney Then you need to provide more context.

Comment: This solution should have worked. @IshanVarshney kindly provide more context (screenshots of what is not being rendered)

Comment: @IshanVarshney Did the obj in ```ParentComponent``` update? Place the console.log in ```useEffect``` and test that out.